# How can I scrape a webpage that only loads it in increments

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to count the number of items that contain the word "kudoed" from a  particular webpage. Now, the webpage itself only loads a limited number of items initally and then requires a button to be pressed to load the rest. Please see the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQtvD.jpg)

I wrote a selenium + beautiful soup code to do this. The reason why I had to use selenium is due to some proxy errors. Here is my full code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = r"C:\Users\H\Desktop\Automated_Tasks\msedgedriver.exe") # Modify the path here...

# Navigate to URL
driver.get("https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/notificationfeed/page")

# Wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Get all elements on the page
time.sleep(8)
click_button=driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/center/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/span/a').click()

element = driver.find_element("ID", 'viewMoreLink')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get the page source
page_source = driver.page_source

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all("div", class_="lia-quilt-column-alley lia-quilt-column-alley-right")

count = 0
for item in items:
    if "kudoed" in item.text:
        count += 1

print(f"Number of items containing 'kudoed': {count}")
```

Is there a way for me to click the button without having to tell selenium to click the button, wait for the next items to load and repeat these steps until the entire list has been loaded?.

When it gets to the code:

```
click_button=driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/center/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/span/a').click()
```

I get the following error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (476, 2184)
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=109.0.1518.61)
```

I tried searching by ID and it still did not work. Here is the full HTML for the button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcDvo.jpg)

Comment: What's the problem with telling selenium to click the button?

Comment: I actually can't get it to work either. I keep getting the error: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (476, 2184)
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=109.0.1518.61)

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and error stacktrace.

Comment: I've just updated my question. Please let me know if you would like me to share any more information.

Comment: There was a few issues with the HTML code but I re uploaded it again

Answer (score 0):

Usually `ElementClickInterceptedException` means that you are trying to click an element not visible on the page, so before clicking it you have to scroll to it.

> Is there a way for me to click the button without having to tell
> selenium to click the button, wait for the next items to load and
> repeat these steps until the entire list has been loaded?

I don't think so, but is not that hard to do the job:

```
items_old, items = [], []
while 1:
    while len(items) == len(items_old):
        items = WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'lia-notification-feed-item')))

    print(f'{len(items)=}')
    show_more_btn = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'viewMoreLink')

    if show_more_btn:
        print('load more items')
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', show_more_btn[0])
        time.sleep(2)
        show_more_btn[0].click()
        items_old = items.copy()
    else:
        print('all items loaded')
        break

print(f"Number of items containing 'kudoed': {sum(['kudoed' in x.text for x in items])}")
```

Output

```
len(items)=25
load more items
len(items)=32
all items loaded
Number of items containing 'kudoed': 2
```